# jquery masonry document ready issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I have launched a site and am still having issues with Jquery Masonry. I have read just about every post about using Document Ready vs Window Load. Everyone except the post that contains an answer for my problem.

Here is the site: http://www.buckysspecialspice.com

Sometimes is loads fine. Today it does not.

my function files reads like this. If I use Document Ready the post blocks sometimes fall together until the browser is resized. If I use Window Load all the post blocks load in rows.

Any advise would be awesome.

```
// MASONRY

function anaximander_masonry() {
if (!is_admin()) {
    wp_register_script('jquery_masonry', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/jquery.masonry.min.js', array('jquery'), '2.0.110526' );
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery_masonry');
    add_action('wp_footer', 'anaximander_add_masonry');

    function anaximander_add_masonry() { ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(window).load(function($){
              var $container = $('img');

                $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
                    $('#masonry-index').masonry({
                        itemSelector: '.index-post-container',
                        isAnimated: true,
                      columnWidth : 3
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php 
    }
}
}

add_action('init', 'anaximander_masonry');
```

Comment: Youy've got a "$ is not a function" error coming up. Try changing that "$" to "jQuery" on the line "$('#masonry-index').masonry({"

Answer (score 0):

@author You probably want $(window).load, since it waits for everything to load (including pictures) before firing and then rearranging stuff by masonry. But what is .imagesLoaded? Does it just trigger a callback after images in the selector have loaded? Why have that and $(window).load?

Also, i'd use "jQuery" instead of "$", since it seems that isn't working (edit: someone beat me to it)

Comment: I'm not sure about the .imageLoaded but when I take it out everything falls apart. But changing the $ seems to work and using Document Ready instead of window load. Thanks for the comments. The site seems to load better now.